# how to add multiple columns from one data frame to another based on values in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames and I want to take the last four columns from df1 and add them to df2 based on the fips code in df2. The fips code is labeled x2 in df1.

```
x1 =c(8000:8003)
mi =c(10:13)
x2 =c(5000:5003)
x21_40 = c(0,0,1,0)
x41_60 = c(1,0,0,0)
x61_80 = c(0,1,0,0)
x81_100 = c(0,0,0,1)
df1 = data.frame(x1,mi,x2, x21_40,x41_60,x61_80, x81_100)

fips = c(5000:5003)
county_name=c("a","b","c","d")
df2 = data.frame(fips, county_name)

> df1
    x1 mi   x2 x21_40 x41_60 x61_80 x81_100
1 8000 10 5000      0      1      0       0
2 8001 11 5001      0      0      1       0
3 8002 12 5002      1      0      0       0
4 8003 13 5003      0      0      0       1

> df2
  fips county_name
1 5000           a
2 5001           b
3 5002           c
4 5003           d
```

Desired

```
  fips county_name x21_40 x41_60 x61_80 x81_100
1 5000           a      0      1      0       0
2 5001           b      0      0      1       0
3 5002           c      1      0      0       0
4 5003           d      0      0      0       1
```

I don't want to merge both data frames, I only want the last four columns, so I don't think it's as simple as using `left_join()`. I have used `%in%` before, but that was only for filtering values in one data frame, based on values in another column from a different data frame. This one has four columns, so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: The problem is the real df1 has x2 out of order. so it doesn't actually go 5000:5003. It's more like 5002,5001,5003,5000. This would just put them right next to each other. There is also a differing number of rows in each data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `left_join` if we want to match the 'x2' from 'df1' and 'fips' from 'df2'

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- left_join(df2, df1 %>%
                select(x2:last_col()), by = c("fips" = "x2"))
```

-output

```
df2
   fips county_name x21_40 x41_60 x61_80 x81_100
1 5000           a      0      1      0       0
2 5001           b      0      0      1       0
3 5002           c      1      0      0       0
4 5003           d      0      0      0       1
```

---

In case of duplicates in 'df1', get the `max` value for those columns grouped by 'fips/x2' and then do the join

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(fips = x2) %>%
   summarise(across(x21_40:x81_100, max, na.rm = TRUE), 
      .groups = "drop") %>%
   left_join(df2, .)
```

Comment: This worked in my little data frame, but when applied to the larger one, it placed zeros in some of the rows where there should have been 1's. I think it's because the real df2 repeats the fips codes (because it's monthly data for that county). so it would look like: 5000,5000,5001,5001,5001,50002 etc. And even though x2, 5000 had a 1 in x41_60, it would not have a one in all the rows that have a 5000 fips code in df2. I don't think I can reproduce the issue, so I'm just going to mark this as answered.

Comment: @bandcar if there are duplicates, then the rows will get doubled as well.   I would consider to use summarised `df1` i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(fips = x2) %>% summarise(across(x21_40:x81_100, max, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>% left_join(df2, .)` i.e. get the max value per 'x2'.  in that case, if there are 0s and 1s, it will return only 1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to augment `df2` with information from `df1`. As long as the fips codes in `df1` are unique ( `df1$x2` ), this should work correctly.

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df2); setDT(df1)
xCols <- grep('_', names(df1), value = TRUE)
df2[df1, c(xCols):=mget(paste('i', xCols, sep='.')), on=.(fips=x2)]
df2
##    fips county_name x21_40 x41_60 x61_80 x81_100
## 1: 5000           a      0      1      0       0
## 2: 5001           b      0      0      1       0
## 3: 5002           c      1      0      0       0
## 4: 5003           d      0      0      0       1
```

If they are not unique, have you considered going in the other direction, augmenting `df1` with the information in `df2`? Each county name has a unique fips code (that is, the combination of state and county fips is unique). Something like:

```
df1[df2[, .N, by=.(fips, county_name)], county:=i.county_name, on=.(x2=fips)]
df1
##      x1 mi   x2 x21_40 x41_60 x61_80 x81_100 county
## 1: 8000 10 5000      0      1      0       0      a
## 2: 8001 11 5001      0      0      1       0      b
## 3: 8002 12 5002      1      0      0       0      c
## 4: 8003 13 5003      0      0      0       1      d
```